# Unable to change Tab bar background color

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using BottomTabNavigator in my project I am unable to change the color of the Tab it's being in default color although I am trying to change the style background color. Following is the code I am using, even the tintcolors also not getting changed. I am attaching the screenshots of the page.
I want to change the color of the bar where the icons present.[image].

```
{
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      tabBarOptions: {
               activeTintColor: 'blue',
          inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
          style: {
            backgroundColor: 'darkcerulean',
            },
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 13,
          },

      }
}
```

Can someone help me with that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: React-navigation:2.9.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use it example:

```
 export default createBottomTabNavigator({
      home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({ 
          title: 'Home'
        })
       }, 
      }, 
     {
        initialRouteName: "home",
        tabBarOptions: {
          style: {
           height: 55,
           backgroundColor: '#8e7e7e'
          }
        }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gurbela but i want to change the background color of the bar(the white bar where we can view the icons) but not the icons hope you understand

Comment: Thanks @gurbela it worked for me(able to change the background color of the bar) but now I am unable to view the icons.

Comment: Choose another color

Comment: or change icon colors

Comment: Tried changing both but no use anyways will try another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The `tabBarOptions` prop was removed and the options from there were moved to screen's options instead <- from the docs.

Now you will need to use:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  ...
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    // any additional screen options here

    tabBarStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#8e7e7e',
    },
  })
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the recognization of the color name `darkcerulean` according to the specifications as mentioned [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/colors#named-colors).

Instead you can try setting the hex color `#08457e`

```
style: {
   backgroundColor: '#08457e',
}
```

Here's a snack [**link**](https://snack.expo.io/S1Vce2YBQ)

Comment: Hey @pritish,  Thanks for your time I have tried with hex code aswell still unable to change

Comment: I've added a snack link to check.

Answer (score 0):

Yon need to set taBarStyle within the screenOptions of the tab navigator:

```
tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: 'yourColor'},
```